# Postgres on conflict

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_or_create_id(scheduleid integer,member_id character varying, user_id integer,role_id integer, _appointment_date timestamp without time zone,active boolean) RETURNS INT AS
$$
WITH get AS (
    SELECT memid FROM member_appointment_details d WHERE appointment_date=_appointment_date
), new AS (
    INSERT INTO member_appointment_details (schedule_id,memberid,userid,roleid,appointment_date,active)
    VALUES (scheduleid,member_id,user_id,role_id,_appointment_date,active)
    
    ON CONFLICT (appointment_date) DO Nothing
    RETURNING memid
)
SELECT memid FROM get
UNION ALL
SELECT memid FROM new
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

table 1
appointment_details has columns :
id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
appointment_date timestamp without time zone

table 2
appointment_schedule
id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
time_duration integer,

now i want to use conflict for the appointment_date from tbl1 with given duration dynamically like 15 mins 20 mins etc
can i use join in this function ? and how to get my exact output?
currently im getting 10:33:00 like this if i give 10:34:00 it is accepting but i want 10:33:00 + 15 mins = 10:48:00 i.e it should accept time + given duration of the given time

Comment: All three PostgreSQL versions you tagged already reached EOL. Consider upgrading your system.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't really clear. Where do you want to add that line, and what is stopping you doing so? What does it have to do with "on conflict"? What is the problem you want us to solve?

Comment: IMSoP i have 2 columns like this '2021-12-01 10:33:00',15 appointment_date and duration respectively here in this function conflict is working properly for the given column. but what is the problem is if i give 10:34:00 it is accepting, it is not taking the duration. the actual answer what i expect is 10:33:00 + duration 15 mins = 10:49:00. it should accept 10:49:00 and greater.

Comment: @IMSoP Also i have a doubt that can i join 2 tables here in this function because the duration comes from another table ...

Comment: @Badrinarayanan Please click the [edit] link under your question, and explain that as clearly as you can. Show the best attempt you've made, the sample data you're using, and the output you get. Also, do your best to remove irrelevant details so that we have an [mcve].